# How to read values from a file and set dynamically into an array in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Im new to python and need to know how to achieve the below requirement

I have a file with values populated as lines separated
for eg.

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
```

I want to read these values from a file and need to set them in the below format in python, basically into a dictionary.
{"Keys":[{"common_key":"ABC"},{"common_key":"DEF"},{"common_key":"GHI"}]}

Dictionary should contain only one Key and its value is an array with set of jsons with a common key assigned with different values each which are read from the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way works for me:

```
with open('filename.txt') as fin :
    lines = [i.strip() for i in fin.readlines() if len(i) > 1]

common_dict = { 'Keys' : [ {'common_key' : i} for i in lines] }
```

Comment: Thanks Lenik and @James,  here im getting the result as : 
{'Keys': [{'common_key': 'ABC'}, {'common_key': 'DEF'}, {'common_key': 'GHI'}]} , whereas I need them to be enclosed in double quotes. Is it possible

Comment: @VishwanathVedantam python uses single quotes by default, if you want doubles, you may use `str(a).replace("'", '"')`, where `a` is your dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would probably be a simple list comprehension. If you need to do any separation logic in the lines str.split() is your friend.

```
with open("filename.txt") as txtfile:
    yourDesiredDict = {"Keys": [{"common_key": x} for x in txtfile.readlines()]}
```

Comment: you forgot to strip the EOL and check for empty lines

Comment: @AMC means `snake_case` and really that's just a [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guideline for styling your code to look professional.